# Reading Bundle.main.path at the launching of the app is time consuming or not?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, swift3

For the App specific i have json file related to environment and configuration, Is it time consuming to read those file at the launch of the app? (Certainly i need it at the launch time) If yes than i will create struct constant using script

```
Bundle.main.path(forResource: ConfigPath.urlString(api: .environment), ofType: "json")
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading from or writing to file is one of the most consuming operations. It's no matter if you do it on an app start. If you want to check how it affects the time launch, you can create a simple UI test and run it with and without file operation.

```objectivec
import XCTest

class UILaunchTests: XCTestCase {
  func testLaunchPerformance() {
    if #available(macOS 10.15, iOS 13.0, tvOS 13.0, *) {
      measure(metrics: [XCTOSSignpostMetric.applicationLaunch]) {
        XCUIApplication().launch()
      }
    }
  }
}
```